# TimePicker Plugin Making It Difficult To Parse String

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, timepicker

I am trying to parse a time in string format to a DateTime using

```
var from = DateTime.Parse(TimeFrom);
```

When the string was like this 7:25 PM  it worked

I then switched to a Timepicker plugin which displays the time like this          7 : 25 : AM

and it no longer works?

How do I change 7 : 25 : AM to 7:25 AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TimeFrom = TimeFrom.Replace(" : ", ":").Replace(":A", " A").Replace(":P", " P");
```

^^ Quick and dirty way to do it.

But I can't understand why the timepicker control would return such an unusually formatted time. Perhaps there is a way to configure it to return the time in a more normal format?

Another approach is to use `DateTime.ParseExact(... )` and specify a format string that describes the format you are seeing.